# np.savetxt triggers ValueError. Why?

Tags: python, valueerror

Earlier in the program, I calculate the matrices P and K. I need the eigenvalues of *PKP*. Since this takes a while (it's a 10000 x 10000 matrix), I want to save the result someplace so it's easily accessible even if I restart the computer.

The last two lines of my program are:

```
eigs=np.linalg.eig(P@K@P)
np.savetxt('eigdata.txt',eigs)
```

This triggers the error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10000,10000)
>   into shape (10000)

Deleting the last time removes the error, so the problem is definitely with `np.savetxt`.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Right before the Value Error...

  File "C:\Users\(my name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

Comment: can you please provide shapes of P and K? seems like error caused by dot product P@K@P

Comment: Try to use also ```np.savez_compressed('eigs.npz',  eigs)```. I think that could be a best option to save huge arrays. Then load it with ```np.load('eigs.npz')['arr_0']```

Comment: P and K are both 10000 x 10000.
Ok, will try Victor Ruiz's suggestion.

Comment: What does the ['arr_0'] mean?

Comment: Just tried closing and reopening Python, then adding the line ```np.load('eigs.npz')['arr_0']```


Got the error message ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False

Answer (score 1):

`np.linalg.eig` outputs two `np.ndarray` one of shape (1000,), the second of shape (1000, 1000). 
You should either save them into different files or use `np.savez` or `np.savez_compressed` istead:

```
np.savez('eigdata', *eigs)
```

And restore them later:

```
w, v = np.load('eigdata.npz').values()
```

Comment: Better ```np.savez_compressed``` for huge arrays.

Comment: As said in my reply to my question... ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False

Comment: well, it's slightly a different problem. try passing `allow_pickle=True` into call that crashes

Comment: Changed it to np.load('eigs.npz',allow_picle=True). 

Got eigOSError: Failed to interpret file 'eigs.npz' as a pickle

Comment: use `allow_pickle=True` in while saving as well

Comment: Alas, np.savez_compressed('eigs.npz',eigs,allow_pickle=True) yielded the error message ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10000,10000) into shape (10000)

Comment: you missed a start `np.savez_compressed('eigs.npz', *eigs, allow_pickle=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple example from `eig`:

```
In [332]: a = np.array([[1, 1j], [-1j, 1]]) 
     ...: w,v = np.linalg.eig(a)                                                                             

In [334]: np.savez('eig.npz', w=w, v=v)                                                                      


In [335]: d = np.load('eig.npz')                                                                             
In [336]: list(d.keys())                                                                                     
Out[336]: ['w', 'v']
In [337]: d['w']                                                                                             
Out[337]: array([2.+0.j, 0.+0.j])
In [338]: d['v']                                                                                             
Out[338]: 
array([[ 0.        +0.70710678j,  0.70710678+0.j        ],
       [ 0.70710678+0.j        , -0.        +0.70710678j]])
```

Or without the keyword names:

```
In [339]: np.savez('eig.npz', w,v)                                                                           
In [340]: d = np.load('eig.npz')                                                                             
In [341]: list(d.keys())                                                                                     
Out[341]: ['arr_0', 'arr_1']
In [342]: d['arr_0']                                                                                         
Out[342]: array([2.+0.j, 0.+0.j])
```

i suspect that if you get a pickle error, it's because you are saving an object like a tuple or dictionary:

```
In [345]: np.savez('eig.npz', {'w':w, 'v':v})                                                                
In [346]: d = np.load('eig.npz')                                                                             
In [347]: list(d.keys())                                                                                     
Out[347]: ['arr_0']
In [348]: d['arr_0']                                                                                         
...
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

Recent numpy versions have become picky about this pickling parameter.

Or you could save the arrays to two files:

```
In [370]: np.save('eig_w.npy',w); np.save('eig_v.npy',v)                                                     
In [371]: np.load('eig_w.npy')                                                                               
Out[371]: array([2.+0.j, 0.+0.j])
In [372]: np.load('eig_v.npy')                                                                               
Out[372]: 
array([[ 0.        +0.70710678j,  0.70710678+0.j        ],
       [ 0.70710678+0.j        , -0.        +0.70710678j]])
```

===

With:

```
In [373]: eigs = np.linalg.eig(a)
In [375]: np.savez('eig.npz', eigs) 
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)
```

That error is produced by a `np.array(eigs)` step.  `np.save` is intended to saving arrays.  Given a tuple it tries to turn it into an array.

Saving `*eigs` is like the `In [339]` example above:

```
In [385]: np.savez('eig.npz', *eigs)                                                                         
In [386]: d = np.load('eig.npz')                                                          
In [387]: list(d.keys())                                                                                     
Out[387]: ['arr_0', 'arr_1']
In [388]: d['arr_1']                                                                                         
Out[388]: 
array([[ 0.        +0.70710678j,  0.70710678+0.j        ],
       [ 0.70710678+0.j        , -0.        +0.70710678j]])
In [389]: d['arr_0']                                                                                         
Out[389]: array([2.+0.j, 0.+0.j])
```