# Another follow-up to numpy.linalg.eig and loading

Tags: numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Anyway, I'm still struggling with the task of 1) Calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix, 2) Saving them to a file, 3) Loading the data back. I can do steps 1 and 2; but no matter what I try step 3 always throws an error. See [np.savetxt triggers ValueError. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322510/np-savetxt-triggers-valueerror-why/57336653) and [Writing and Reading Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors, follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336227/writing-and-reading-eigenvalues-eigenvectors-follow-up)

This time I tried saving the eigenvalues and eigenvectors separately, so they're both arrays. Unfortunately I still get the pickle error. Even when loading just the eigenvalues.

```
eigs=np.linalg.eig(P@K@P)
eigvals=np.real(eigs[0])
eigvecs=np.real(eigs[1])
np.savetxt('eigvals.txt',eigvals)
np.savetxt('eigvecs.txt',eigvecs)
```

Sure enough, eigvals and eigvecs show up as arrays, sizes 10000 and 10000x10000 respectively, in the Variable Explorer. And when I manually open eigvals.txt, I see a long list of floats as expected. But when I then try np.load('eigvals.txt','r'), I still get the pickle error (ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False). What's wrong now?

Thanks

Comment: In terms of follow-up questions it's usually done by opening up new questions. This allows better search for other users. In general, each question though, should be [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (your example for example is nothing we can run to verify your problem; and you did not show the error you observe!). Also: why are you trying np.savetext and not np.save? Try to show some reproducible example. And whats wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336601/2320035) answer?

Comment: Your first question belongs on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: If you turn this into one question, I will trade my down for an up.

Comment: Sorry, didn't even know about Meta StackOverflow. First question removed.

Ok, it looks like save should be paired with load, and savetxt with loadtxt, but not a mix-and-match. On another piece of advice, managed to get the data to load with savetxt and loadtxt. Thanks

Unfortunately, when I tried to confirm the calculations using the equation Av=lambda v for a specific eigenvector/eigenvalue, they failed to match. Will see if I can reproduce this with a convenient-size matrix.

Comment: What's this `Variable Explorer`?

Comment: It's a tab, next to File Explorer. Displays variables and their values on the top right of the screen, above the Console.

Comment: @J.D. Are you using an IDE of some sort?  `Variable Explorer` isn't native to python.

Comment: When you respond directly to a comment, that poster does get a notification of your response.  But they don't have to reply back - then, or later, or ever.  This isn't a paid help-line.

Comment: I gave a small working example in my reply to your first question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336653/901925